# How to use cloudfoundry client python module

Tags: python, cloud-foundry, cf-python-client

I am new to `CloudFoundry`. I want to access my apps information and even I want to try to create an app using python in `CloudFoundry` using `cloudfoundry-client` python module.

```
cloudfoundry_client.CloudFoundryClient("https://api.run.pivotal.io","cf",'',None,False)
```

I have used in my python command line and it is showing error.
Can anyone help me to connect to my `CloudFoundry` using python to create and mange my apps.

**EDIT**

Error Message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module> cloudfoundry_client.CloudFoundryClient("https://api.run.pivotal.io","cf",'',None‌​,False) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cloudfoundry_client\client.py", line 25, in __init__ self.info = caller.get('%s/info' % self.target_endpoint).json() TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: Hi, can you show us what is the error message?

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: I tried. I don't have any document for that how to use that module, Any one can share if the material is available

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login using username and password do it like this:

```
client = cloudfoundry_client.CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint='https://api.run.pivotal.io')
client.init_with_credentials(login='example@gmail.com', password='secret')
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to connect to cf-python-client module

```
target_endpoint="https://api.[cf-api-domain].com"
proxy = dict(http=os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY', ''), https=os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY', ''))
client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, proxy=proxy, verify=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials( 'admin', 'password' )
```

and this is how you get all the details of all apps in the target_endpoint

```
for app in client.v2.apps:
    print app
```